# Changing expanded reference style to compressed

Tags: natbib

I am having difficulties formatting the reference style in a template. I have added `\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}` to force compressed reference style to my document, however it is not giving me the desired result. Rather than formatting the references as [1-5] it is formatting them as [1,2,3,4,5]. I have attached a screenshot for reference. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

[image]

I have included the top definitions for the document below

```
\documentclass[journal]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Optik}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `elsarticle` document class loads the `natbib` package automatically. Thus, the instruction

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
```

comes too late if LaTeX encounters it *after* the `\documentclass` directive.

Incidentally, the options `numbers` and `super` are mutually exclusive; which citation call-out style to do you actually need?

The options `square` and `comma` are active by default, so no need to set them explicitly.

Assuming you want `numbers`, which is also the default with the `elsarticle` document class, the easiest fix I can think of is to place the option `sort&compress` among the arguments of the `\documentclass` directive, i.e., to write

```
\documentclass[journal,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

For the sake of good housekeeping, I'd also delete -- or comment out -- the redundant `\usepackage{natbib}` directive.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,sort&compress]{elsarticle}

% create a sample bib file "on the fly"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib} 
@misc{a:3001,author={A},title={KLM},year=3001}
@misc{b:3002,author={B},title={NOP},year=3002}
@misc{c:3003,author={C},title={QRS},year=3003}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\journal{Optik}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} % select a suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{a:3001,c:3003}, 
\cite{a:3001,b:3002,c:3003}
\bibliography{mybib} % entries are listed in order of first citation in doc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like my references to be formatted such as [1,2] or for 3 or more references [1-3]. The citation style you suggested is exactly what I need. I added the `\setcitestyle` after the `\documentclass` directive and removed the redundant directives. After compiling twice there is still no change to the reference style in the document. The references remain ungrouped. Could the `elsarticle` package be overriding the style? If so how could I override the package, short of diving into the class file? Or is there an easier fix to this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Keith - Please see the update to my answer. Moving `sort&compress` to the list of arguments of `\documentclass` got the job done. I just saw that you posted a separate answer, which also works. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

After messing around for a while, I found a solution that works in my case. Firstly I changed `\usepackage[journal]{elsarticle}` to `\usepackage[journal,nonatbib]{elsarticle}` to disable `natbib` being used by the class template. The line `\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` now works as intended. So apparently something in the template class was preventing natbib from taking in optional arguments. The final code is shown below for clarity.

```
\documentclass[journal,nonatbib]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```